# Get publicly accessible URL from Google Cloud after upload PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

The problem is after I upload an object to my publicly accessible Google Cloud bucket, I want to use the created URL immediately for another service. However, I don't see a way to get the mediaUrl that I could then use. All of the properties on the following method that would give me that are private:

```
$bucket->upload(
    fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r'),
    array('name' => $name)
);
```

I've already tried var_dump-ing the above method to see if any of the public properties would give me the created URL, but it doesn't even have any public properties.

Here's the code I'm using to upload the data:

```php
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' => 'keyfile_json.json'
]);
$bucket = $storage->bucket('bucket');

$name = 'some/name/path/'.$_POST['name'];

    $bucket->upload(
        fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r'),
        array('name' => $name)
);
```

The file is uploading, I just can't get the URL of the actual resource that I can then go use in a different API call to a different service.

**How can I get the URL of the resource after it is uploaded?**

Comment: You might want to look into creating something called a "signed URL" after the upload completes, which will provide public access to the object.  If the other service is a Google Cloud API, you might instead be able to build and pass a "gs://" URL to it, such as the Google Cloud Speech API allows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways to achieve this:

1. Creating the URL for public objects using the following sintaxis: https://storage.googleapis.com/[BucketName]/[ObjectName]

Where:

[BucketName] = your bucket

[ObjectName]= name of your uploaded object

2. If you are using AppEngine Standard Environment, there is a method in the API PHP App Engine API: getPublicUrl(string $gs_filename, boolean $use_https) : string

Where:

$gs_filename, string, The Google Cloud Storage filename, in the format: gs://bucket_name/object_name.

$use_https, boolean, If True then return a HTTPS URL. Note that the development server ignores this argument and returns only HTTP URLs.

Here the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.cloud_storage.CloudStorageTools#method_getPublicUrl).

Answer (score 6):

You need to build the public Link URL yourself for public objects.

The format is simple `https://storage.cloud.google.com/BucketName/ObjectName`.

Comment: So I've been trying that, and when I put that into like a browser bar or Postman or something else like that, it always redirects me to the google login page

Comment: Then your new object ACL is not public. Double-check the permissions (ACLs) that you are assigning to the object or have assigned to the bucket.

Comment: So I have the allUsers permission set on the bucket and I have disabled the object ACLs and I'm still getting the redirect to the google login screen.

Comment: I have answered your original question. Close this question and create a new question that includes the details on the Bucket ACL and IAM permissions.